# Why does Retrofit use Interface instead of a normal java class?

Tags: java, android-studio, interface, retrofit, retrofit2

In my Android, I am using Retrofit to implement an http client.
Retrofit uses interfaces to define the possible http operations.

> userInterface.java

```
UserInterface.java
public interface UserInterface {
   // Retrofit callback
   @POST("login")
   Call<Integer> signin(@Body LoginActivity.UserInfo userInfo);
}
```

This UserInterface is then used by retrofit in the loginActivity.java:

> loginActivity.java

```
// It makes sense. Retrofit will use the interface as a configuration file
UserInterface userInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(UserInterface.class);
```

> ApiClient.java

```
public static Retrofit getApiClient(){
   if (retrofit==null){
       retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .build();
   }
   return retrofit;
};
```

I understood everything about how Retrofit Client configuration and how it works. However, I couldn't see why userInterface is a java interface instead of a normal java class?
I know that in a nutshell this is what an interface is:

> An interface is a reference type in Java. It is similar to class. It is a collection of abstract methods. A class implements an interface,
>   thereby inheriting the abstract methods of the interface.      Along
>   with abstract methods, an interface may also contain constants,
>   default methods, static methods, and nested types. Method bodies exist
>   only for default methods and static methods.
>
> Writing an interface is similar to writing a class. But a class
>   describes the attributes and behaviors of an object. And an interface
>   contains behaviors that a class implements.
>
> Unless the class that implements the interface is abstract, all the
>   methods of the interface need to be defined in the class.

I have also understood the particular role of the interface with Retrofit:

> You can see the interface as a configuration file, it holds info
>   (method declaration , return type and params, annotations) about each
>   endpoint (link a method name to url, GET or POST, parameters and
>   parameter types, return value type , ... and more). the engine uses
>   those info to serialize parameters (if needed), execute the request
>   and deserialize the response (if needed).

However, I still cannot explain to myself **the use of an interface instead of a normal java class**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code of the [Retrofit library](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Retrofit.java), in particular the `create()` method of `Retrofit.java` class, you can see that they're using [Java's Dynamic Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) approach to create classes at runtime.

This mechanism requires an interface (or a list of interfaces) in order to create proxy classes that have particular behaviour. This explains why the use of an interface instead of normal java class.